# Java: How to create a queue based on a Node class

Tags: java, queue, nodes

I'm trying to create a queue using two classes, a Node class and a Queue class for an assignment. Here's the node class:

```
class Node
{
 protected Node next;

 public Node()
 {
    next = null;
 }
}
```

This class basically links the data together using a Node.next object. I've successfully been able to create a stack with push() and pop(), because the two operations happen on the same end, so the point are just manipulated between pointing to a new added node, and the previous node.

However, I'm having some difficulties understanding the logic to create a queue based on a similar structure. My queue class looks something like this:

```
class Queue
{
 private Node footer;
 private Node header;

 public Queue()
 {
    footer = null;
    header = null;
 }

 public void add(Node newNode)
 {   
    //Adds onto the queue from the 'footer' end.
 }  

 public Node remove()
 {
    //Removes from the queue from the 'header' end.
 }
```

Here's what I understand: (1)The header and the footer point to the same first node. (2) Subsequent adding should change the footer to point to the added nodes, but the header stays on the first node added. (3) The header should point to the next oldest node upon removal.

Here's what I can't figure out (and where it's different than popping from a stack). How do I get the header to point to the 'next oldest node', given that I have more than 2 nodes in this queue? I know I can do this if I link header.next to the next node in the queue, but how can I access the next node so that it can point to it?

I thought about how in add(), the newNode.next should point to the next newNode (reverse direction of a Stack), but this can't work because the next newNode isn't in existence yet.. Another idea was to modify the Node class to have a Node.previous for a way to point backwards, but I would be breaking specification for this assignment.

My instructor hinted something about "header.next will point for second item as header and footer point to first node initially," and that the way to do this is pretty simple. However, I've been drawing how this works, and I'm confused how the initial pointing to the same node will allow header.next to "automatically" point to the next oldest node, especially if more and more nodes are added and the footer eventually is separated from the header by more than 2 nodes. Is there something about OOP I'm not seeing?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Look up how linked lists work. That will help you probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on, and offer a subtle alternative to @Sanjeev's answer (one that I think your instructor was hinting to):

Rather than using `footer` to store "actual" nodes, use it as a placeholder: Declare it as a `final` variable, initialize it in your constructor and make sure that either a) it's `next` node is always your `header` (this would be called a [circular list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_list)), or its `next` node is null.

Can you see how this solves your "this can't work because the next newNode isn't in existence yet" problem: Of course you can't point the last node added to the next one that will be added before adding it - instead, you point it to this "dummy" node - which is a *placeholder* for the next node that will be added, when and if it is.

```
add(Node newestNode){
   identify the last node added as the one whose next property is the footer. 
   change the next property of that node from footer to this new newestNode 
   set the next property of this new newestNode to footer 
}
```

It would be preferable to identify that last node added as the one that footer is pointing to (rather than the one pointing to footer), which would be easy if you were allowed to have `previous` as well as `next` properties on nodes, but it sounds like you're not allowed to do that. Of course, since we're using footer as a "dummy node", we could simply use `footer.next` the way we would `footer.previous` and have it point backwards instead of forwards, but I'll leave you to consider how clean that would be. There are other options here that I'll leave you to consider as well.

> How do I get the header to point to the 'next oldest node'`

The "oldest" node was the first one added. The "newest" node is the last one added. How is the order of the rest of the nodes stored? The same way it was in your Stack - by traversing a chain of references stored as instance variables on your nodes. The main point I want to make is that Stacks and Queues, when implemented as [linked data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data_structure), are much more similar than you seem to be thinking, at least from a : Iterating through any *linked* data structure is done by following traversing these *links* - don't get too hung up on the fact that you're "moving" in a different direction - the same basic principles apply:

```
Node remove(){ 
    identify the "oldest" node as header.next. 
    Store a reference to that node so you can return it. 
    identify the "second oldest node" as header.next.next 
    change header.next to header.next.next
    return the reference to the old header.next you saved above.
```

(Note that using header/footer as placeholders, rather than storing "actual" nodes in them as @Sanjeev suggests, is not necessary, but it'll make your life easier - for instance, by helping you avoid a lot of null checking)

Comment: Hey drewmore, thanks for the additional comments! Looking at @Sanjeev's answer, it's amazing how similar the coding it is compared to the one I did for my stakes. In fact the `remove()` is almost literally the same! However, I'm still seeing it as a directional problem, because for `head = head.next`, isn't this pointing in the opposite direction? From the `add()`, `head = newNode`, and isn't `newNode.next == null`? If this is the case, then aren't we going in the opposite direction to a world of `null`s whereas the other direction actually leads to the nodes in the stack/queue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sudo code that will help you get started.

```
public void add(Node newNode)
 {   
    if footer is null ?
    then
     header = newNode and footer = newNode;
    else 
     footer.next = newNode and footer = newNode;
    end if
 }

 public Node remove()
 {
    Node returnMe = header;
    if header is not null?
    then
      header = header.next
      if header is null
      then
         footer = null;
      endif
    end if
    return returnMe;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get the header to point to the 'next oldest node', given that
>   I have more than 2 nodes in this queue? I know I can do this if I link
>   header.next to the next node in the queue, but how can I access the
>   next node so that it can point to it?

To make header point to that node, you only need do `header = header.next`. The reason is that Java objectt assignment is by reference. Since header.next is type of Node, header is type of Node, it will copy the address of header.next to header, i.e., header is advanced one place.

> I thought about how in add(), the newNode.next should point to the
>   next newNode (reverse direction of a Stack), but this can't work
>   because the next newNode isn't in existence yet..

I think it is no need to considering reverse direction. The reason is because for adding , it is to add element to the tail/footer of the queue. The only special case is that the queue didn't have any elements (`footer == header == null`), 1 element : (`footer = header = element`), other case: header won't change, but you need to append element to footer, and then make footer point to the new node.

When only 1 element, `footer.next == header.next == null`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you need to do is make sure the first node you create is the oldest so it should be the first to be removed  from the Queue based on  First In First Out (FIFO) principle to archive this you might need to modify you're add method to something like this, by the way this example is based on single linked list implementation.

```
   void add(char new_data) 
{ 

    /* 1. alloc the Node and put data*/
    Node new_Node = new Node(new_data); 

    /* 2. Make next of new Node as head */
    new_Node.next = head; 

    /* 3. Move the head to point to new Node */
    head = new_Node; 
}
```

then you will need a remove method which will remove the oldest node on the list first remember in Queue the order of remove is First In First Out (FIFO) 
that being said this remove method should help you

```
    void remove() 
{ 
    // Store head node 
    Node temp = head, prev = null; 

    // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted 
    if (temp != null ) 
    { 
        head = temp.next; // Changed head 
        return; 
    } 

    // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the 
    // previous node as we need to change temp.next 
    while (temp != null) 
    { 
        prev = temp; 
        temp = temp.next; 
    }     

    // If key was not present in linked list 
    if (temp == null) return; 

    // Unlink the node from linked list 
    prev.next = temp.next; 
}
```

This worked for me on my linked list